# Extract number from tf.Tensor model

Tags: tensorflow, model, prediction

I am using `softmax` to get the probability vector from a CNN-MFCC based model.  I've started to use the command

```
model(prediction_feature)
```

instead of

```
 model.predict(prediction_feature)
```

as I kept getting warning messages while passing the `model.predict` command over a loop.  However, now when I record the probability, the value gets returned in the form:

```
tf.Tensor(0.00087791355, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

instead for just the number 0.00087791355 when I use the `model.predict` command.

Is there a way to extract just the number from the `model(prediction_feature)` approach?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible code. It's ambiguous to answer from the current state.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a tensor to a `NumPy` array either using `numpy.array(tensor)` or the `tensor.numpy()` method.

**For example:**

```
import numpy
model(prediction_feature).numpy()
#Or
numpy.array(model(prediction_feature))
```

However, please let us know the warning messages you get while using `model.predict(prediction_feature)`.